# how to update the adapter in recyclerview for particular item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My **Adapter class**

```
package com.app.watermangement.httpClient.Model;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.app.watermangement.R;
import com.app.watermangement.httpClient.Constants;
import com.app.watermangement.httpClient.HttpRequest;
import com.app.watermangement.httpClient.URL;

import java.util.List;

public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Data> dataList;


    private OnItemClickListener mListener;



    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position,int id);
    }

    public Context ctx;

    public void setOnItemListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public ProductAdapter(Context ctx,List<Data> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
        this.ctx  = ctx;


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int position) {


        Data data = dataList.get(position);
        Log.d("id's",data.getId().toString());
        myViewHolder.id.setText(data.getId().toString());


        if (data.getStatus() != null) {
            Log.d("getStatus",data.getStatus().toString());
            myViewHolder.aBoolean.setChecked(toBoolean(data.getStatus()));

        } else {
            Log.d("GetStatus", "is Null");
        }

        notifyItemChanged(myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());



//        myViewHolder.bindData(dataList.get(position));


//        myViewHolder.aBoolean.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                Log.d("HII", String.valueOf(position + 1));
//            }
//        });
    }


    public boolean toBoolean(String value) {
        if (value != null) {
            if (value.equals("Motor is running")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }
       return true;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView id;
        public Switch aBoolean;
        public HttpRequest httpRequest;



        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            aBoolean = (Switch)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rectangleSwitch);
            int pos = getAdapterPosition();


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                            mListener.onItemClick(position,dataList.get(position).getId());
                    }
                }
            });


            aBoolean.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();

                }
            });

        }
    }

}
```

**my activity class**

```
package com.app.watermangement.httpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.app.watermangement.EditMotorNameActivity;
import com.app.watermangement.R;
import com.app.watermangement.ResponseHandler;
import com.app.watermangement.httpClient.Model.Data;
import com.app.watermangement.httpClient.Model.ProductAdapter;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StatusClass extends AppCompatActivity implements ResponseHandler, ProductAdapter.OnItemClickListener{



    private HttpRequest httpRequest;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ProductAdapter productAdapter;
    private List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Button updateMotorStatus;
    private ArrayList<Integer> motorId = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_statusclass);
        httpRequest = new HttpRequest();

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        updateMotorStatus = findViewById(R.id.updateMotorStatus);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.actionbar_space_between_icon_and_title);
        }
        ApiRequest();
        GetMotorList();
    }

    private void ApiRequest(){
        Utils.startLoadingScreen(StatusClass.this);
        httpRequest.request(StatusClass.this, null, Constants.REQUEST_SYS_DEVICE_LIST, new URL().getBaseURL(StatusClass.this) + URL.DEVICE_LIST);

    }

    private void GetMotorList() {

        updateMotorStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (motorId != null) {
                    for (Integer id : motorId) {
                        Log.d("id'sfrom",id.toString());
                        httpRequest.request(StatusClass.this, null, Constants.REQUEST_MOTOR_STATE_EACH_MOTOR,
                                new URL().getBaseURL(StatusClass.this) + URL.MOTOR_STATE_ID + id);


                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(StatusClass.this, "Empty Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void responseHandler(Object response, int requestType) {

        switch (requestType) {
            case Constants.REQUEST_SYS_DEVICE_LIST:
                Utils.cancelLoadingScreen();
                if(response != null){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)response;
                    try {
                    if (jsonObject.getString("result").equals("Success")) {
                        Log.d("deviceList", String.valueOf(jsonObject));
                        JSONObject result_str = null;
                        result_str = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result_str");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = result_str.getJSONArray("device_list");
                        for (int i =0; i < jsonArray.length();i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);

                            motorId.add(jsonObject1.getInt("device_id"));


//                            Utils.startLoadingScreen(StatusClass.this);
//                            httpRequest.request(StatusClass.this, null, Constants.REQUEST_MOTOR_STATE_EACH_MOTOR,
//                                    new URL().getBaseURL(StatusClass.this) + URL.MOTOR_STATE_ID + jsonObject1.getInt("device_id"));

                            Data data =new Data();
                            data.setId(jsonObject1.getInt("device_id"));
                            dataList.add(data);
                        }

                        productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(this,dataList);
                        productAdapter.setOnItemListener(this);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(productAdapter);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Some thing went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                break;

            case Constants.REQUEST_MOTOR_ON:
                Utils.cancelLoadingScreen();
                Log.d("Statuson",response.toString());
                if (response!= null) {


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Some thing went wrong ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

            case Constants.REQUEST_MOTOR_STATE_EACH_MOTOR:
                Utils.cancelLoadingScreen();
                if(response != null) {
                    JSONObject motorStatusObj = (JSONObject) response;
                    try {
                        JSONObject js = motorStatusObj.getJSONObject("result_str");
                        Log.d("Motor State Status",js.getString("Motor State"));
                        Data data1 = new Data();
                        data1.setStatus(js.getString("Motor State"));
                        Log.d("Status Get",data1.getStatus());
                        dataList.add(data1);
                        productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position,int id) {
        Utils.startLoadingScreen(StatusClass.this);
        Log.d("Position", String.valueOf(position));
        Log.d("Postion ID", String.valueOf(id));
        httpRequest.request( StatusClass.this, null, Constants.REQUEST_MOTOR_ON, new URL().getBaseURL((Activity) StatusClass.this) + URL.MOTOR_ON + "=" + dataList.get(position).getId());
    }
}
```

My requirement is `recyclerview` two fileds is available one field is in one api request another one is another api request, firstly when activity created I am placing the request and show data list to `recyclerview`, later I placed one button on click on that button I will make another request I will recieve the data to update the next field of `recyclerview`. My problem second field is not updated to `recyclerview`.

```
package com.app.watermangement.httpClient.Model;

public class Data  {
    private int id;
    private String status;



    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String i) {
        this.status = i;
    }
}
```

[image: motor1 is one field and toggle is one field both the data coming from different api's]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [notifyItemChanged(int position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object)) to update a specific item in `RecyclerView`.

From documentation:

> Notify any registered observers that the item at position has changed with an optional payload object.
>
> This is an item change event, not a structural change event. It
> indicates that   any reflection of the data at position is out of date
> and should be updated. The item at position retains the same identity.